# How to check if key exists or not using json-path library?

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm using [Json Path](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path/4.1.2) library and I want to check if key exists or not and based on that I'll do some actions. Hence I wrote following code -

```
for(int i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i++) {
  List<String> invalidKeys = new ArrayList<>();

  if(Objects.isNull(jsonPath.getString(key))) {
     invalidKeys.add(key);
     continue;
  }else {
     value = keyValues[i].split("=")[1];
  }
}
```

My intention to get keys which are not present in json but with this code, if key has value as `null` that is also treated non-existing key. Is there any way I can modify above code to get only keys which are not present in json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your jsonPath to build a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonPath.prettify());
```

Then you can use this jsonObject to check if the key exists:

```
for(int i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i++) {
  List<String> invalidKeys = new ArrayList<>();

  if(!jsonObject.has(key)) {
     invalidKeys.add(key);
     continue;
  }else {
     value = keyValues[i].split("=")[1];
  }
}
```